# When using ISO silent install, is there a function to prevent download updates during ubuntu installation?

Tags: 20.04

Create an ISO using the Ubuntu 20.04.2 file.
When you connect a network line and the ISO installation is complete, a prompt window appears during the automatic download of additional packages, causing the installation to be abnormal.
What I want is to prevent the automatic download of additional packages after installation.

Is there a function to prevent download updates while installing ubuntu?

The ISO file must write 20.04.2.

Comment: I'm confused by your question (*and you weren't specific as to what Ubuntu 20.04.2 product you're asking about*), but preventing the automatic network isn't difficult as QA-test installs are made with & without networking and it's up to the tester how this is done (it's not difficult), but **after** the installation as you mention (ie. *I read it as after first boot*) the user controls what occurs (*during install too; but methods available vary on 20.04.2 & *unspecified* installer in use)

Comment: @guiverc
To elaborate on the process,
Use the cubic program and ubuntu 20.04.2 image file, and create a fully automatic installation file using the preseed.

After the above operation, proceed to the ISO installation, but after the file installation is complete, a prompt appears during the package update process and the installation becomes abnormal.

What I want is to run right after rebooting without updating the package after installing ISO. Is there a way like this?